# Mysql: Subtraction between rows and sum with other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, both with a Time column as timestamp type which is filled by default when the row is created: Table1 is updated approximately every 10 seconds:

```
         Time       | Val_1a | Val_2a | Val_3a 
2021-11-06 13:59:53 |  15    |  10    |  35
2021-11-06 14:00:02 |  12    |  15    |  34
.................         
2021-11-06 14:05:25 |  11    |  13    |  35
2021-11-06 14:05:35 |  11    |  17    |  36
```

Table2 is updated every hour after mathematical operations on table1:

```
         Time       | Var_1b | Var_2b | Var_3b            
2021-11-06 11:00:00 |  2     |  15    |  30
2021-11-06 12:00:00 |  8     |  12    |  32
2021-11-06 13:00:00 |  12    |  11    |  35
```

What I would like to get but I'm not able to do in any way, is:

1. Check that the last table1.Val_2a value is greater than the first table1.Val_2a value written at the beginning of the current hour (with the tables above, check if 17 > 15). If this condition is not met, the entire query must return 0 otherwise:

2a) If the last row in table2 refers to the previous day, then the query result is simply the difference of the two table1.Val_2a values (17 - 15 = 2)

2b) Otherwise their difference is calculated as at point 2a (17-15 = 2) and it is added to the table2.Var_1b value (2 + 12 = 14)

I hope I was able to explain it in a clearly way, and that it all is possible with a single query. Thanks everyone for the support

Comment: start by telling us which version and what you triedn so far

Comment: I'm struggling to see the significance of val1 and val3 to this problem

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin 5.1.0. Forget val1 and val3, they'r not used anymore. I'm getting what I need step by step with a script using common queries like: "SELECT Val_2a FROM table1 WHERE Time >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1" --> "SELECT Val_2a FROM table1 WHERE Time >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") ORDER BY Time LIMIT 1" --> "SELECT Time FROM table2 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1" All the rest (if clause, etc) is made within the script that I want to avoid

Comment: I've tryed putting some step together with LAST_VALUE() / FISRT_VALUE() Function, for example, but I always get errors

Comment: Note that an edit button is provided

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if I add an Answer but I couldn't add the image into the comment.
This is the qwery I used to test the CASE clause

> SELECT t1.dtm, t1.Val_2a2, t1.Val_2a1,
> CASE WHEN Val_2a2 > Val_2a1
> THEN Val_2a2-Val_2a1 ELSE 0 END AS ValF FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') dtm,
> SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Val_2a ORDER BY time),',',1) Val_2a1,
> SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Val_2a ORDER BY time DESC),',',1) Val_2a2 FROM table1 GROUP BY dtm) t1

and this is the unexpected result
[Qwery result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c2iR.jpg)

Comment: Making more test it seems to work better adding ABS() function here: "CASE WHEN ABS(Val_2a2) > ABS(Val_2a1)".  Val_2a is a float(9,1) type in table1, and anyway it is always a positive value!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in a single query but different people will have different method of doing it. Whatever the method is, I personally think that the most important part is to keep the logic intact. The details you've provided in your question got me assuming that this might be a kind of query you're looking for:

```
SELECT t1.dtm, t1.Val_2a2, t1.Val_2a1, t2.Val_1b2,
       CASE WHEN Val_2a2 > Val_2a1 
            THEN Val_2a2-Val_2a1+Val_1b2 ELSE 0 END AS ValF
FROM
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') dtm,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Val_2a ORDER BY time),',',1) Val_2a1 ,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Val_2a ORDER BY time DESC),',',1) Val_2a2
FROM table1
GROUP BY dtm) t1 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DATE(time) dtm,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Val_1b ORDER BY time DESC),',',1) Val_1b2
FROM table2
GROUP BY dtm) t2
ON DATE(t1.dtm)=t2.dtm;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2eb85e814169a7caa00d9cec65b706f)

Comment: Thanks, I'm improving so much thanks to your answer. I'm studying it step by step but the case clause doesn't seem to work properly. I noticed something unexpected in the results so I went deeper just whit this qwery "SELECT t1.dtm, t1.Val_2a2, t1.Val_2a1,
       CASE WHEN Val_2a2 > Val_2a1 
            THEN Val_2a2-Val_2a1 ELSE 0 END AS ValF
FROM
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') dtm,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Val_2a ORDER BY time),',',1) Val_2a1,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Val_2a ORDER BY time DESC),',',1) Val_2a2
FROM table1GROUP BY dtm) t1"

Answer (score 0):

hoping it can help someone else, after some more test this is the final qwery I got, considering I just need a value on the fly without needing of storing it.
Of course every consideration by the experts is more than appreciate.
Thanks to all

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN
        (ABS(t1.Val_2a2) - ABS(t1.Val_2a1)) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
            THEN t1.Val_2a2-t1.Val_2a1+t2.Val_1b2
            ELSE t2.Val_1b2
    END AS My_result
FROM
        (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') dtm,
        (SELECT Val_2a FROM table1 WHERE Time >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") ORDER BY Time LIMIT 1) Val_2a1,
        (SELECT Val_2a FROM table1 WHERE Time >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1) Val_2a2
FROM table1
GROUP BY dtm
ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1) t1 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT (Time) dtm,
       (Val_1b) Val_1b2
FROM table2
GROUP BY dtm ORDER BY dtm DESC LIMIT 1) t2 
ON DATE(t1.dtm)= DATE(t2.dtm)
```